# High-res / high quality, public domain cell / bacteria images on the web for download

Tags: data, photography

Wondering if there are any high quality, high res images of eukaryotic cells or bacteria on the web available for download (public domain). I found some [*illustrations*](https://www.cdc.gov/media/subtopic/images.htm) which are public domain, they look nice, but they are *illustrations*. I would like to find SEM electron micrograph images or things of that nature, microscope images in the public domain.

[Here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a6/Escherichia_coli_%28SEM%29.jpg) is an SEM image that is somewhat acceptable, though it has the legend built into the image and isn't colorized (colorization would be a bonus). [Here](https://phil.cdc.gov/Details.aspx?pid=10070) is a colorized image.

[This](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Microscopic_images_of_Escherichia_coli#/media/File:E_coli_at_10000x,_original.jpg) is more the quality I am looking for.

[This](http://cellimagelibrary.org/images/11110) is decent, but it's not public domain.

[These](http://remf.dartmouth.edu/Amorphophallus_titanum_SEM/) are great!

I wish some of [these](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/346073552594036394/?lp=true) were public domain.

Comment: What do you want to do with them? Is it commercial use as suggested by your attitude to a CC image? Nobody ca stop you downloading for private use unless they are watermarked.

Comment: I want to give them away and let others sell them

Comment: Then — and in any case — this doesn’t appear to be a question about biology in the terms of SE Biology, I’m afraid.